# Multiple selection in single Dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this code on reddit that works quite well. Anyway, when I try to delete the information that I completed with the dropdown, or modify something, an undefined value shows up and I can not delete it. How could I do that?

Code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart != 6 || e.oldValue == undefined) return;
  e.range.setValue(e.oldValue+" | "+e.value);
}
```

[image: Screenshot:]

Besides, when more than 1 option is added on my cell, an 'invalid' message shows up. How could I delete it? It's a default config from the Data Validation.
[image: invalid message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far your code snippet works on mine properly. (I can't seem to replicate your issue)

But for you, it isn't (that I am not sure). Try to include the condition where `e.value` is null (that happens when you delete the cell value). Your code should look like this.

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart != 6 || e.oldValue == null || e.value == null) return;
  e.range.setValue(e.oldValue+" | "+e.value);
}
```

#### Note:

- Try to log the values before comparing them in a condition. It's true that in a `==` sense, `null` and `undefined` are the same as both of them return `FALSE`, but they have different types. If you have used `===`, then they are not equal.
- If the cell is deleted (as you can see on the image below), both `oldValue` and `value` becomes `null`.

#### Cloud logs (blank -> yes -> no -> delete cell):

[image: output]

Comment: It worked! thank you very much!
Another little issue to solve: As this is a dropdown and I am adding 2 values to a cell. An 'invalid error message ' shows up, that I'd need to clean up. However, sheets doesn't provide me that option. Any clue?

Comment: Hi @NicolasMEDVEDY, I can't really visualize your issue. You can try to update your post and add the issue (what you did, illustration on what happened and what your expected output should be), but I prefer you post it as another question since that is actually a different matter and not related to the issue in this question. But if you edit your post here and notify me, then I might be able to look at it right after.

Comment: Oh, that's normal when you did it via `Data Validation`. That's because it is considered invalid data as it wasn't an option in your original list of items. Just neglect that warning, it won't change the value nor do anything bad. just shows you that the option showing is not among the original list of items. @NicolasMEDVEDY

Comment: yes I know but I intended to avoid it for keeping the sheet cleaner. thanks anyway!